# Requirement of requirement not installing when installing with pip

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging

When using pip to install, a requirement of a requirement is not being installed.

[dedupe](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe) requires 
[pylbfgs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyLBFGS), which requires`numpy 1.12.1` or greater.

But when I install dedupe from a directory

```
> git clone git@github.com:dedupeio/dedupe.git
> cd dedupe
> pip install --upgrade pip
> pip install .
...
Collecting Levenshtein_search (from dedupe==1.6.13)
Downloading Levenshtein_search-1.4.4-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (59kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 8.5MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9 in /home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from fastcluster->dedupe==1.6.13)
Collecting pylbfgs (from rlr>=2.4.3->dedupe==1.6.13
Downloading PyLBFGS-0.2.0.5-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (159kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 7.4MB/s 
...
> pip freeze
...
numpy==1.9.1
...
```

I would have expected that pip would have checked the requirements of `pylbfgs` and seen that a `numpy >= 1.12.1` was necessary, but that did not happen. I don't know if it has to do with `pip` checking the `numpy` dependency of `Levenshtein_search` and finding that it was met.

Full traceback is here: https://travis-ci.org/dedupeio/dedupe/jobs/232943131

Comment: Related: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988

Comment: This is basically the answer. If you respond as an answer, I'd accept this.